# Appropriate Synonym for 'accelerated' in thesis title

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, adverbs, titles

I have the following thesis title:

> On the acceleration of X Methods: superfast Y Solver for Z

My thesis goal and reached objective is **"Improving X and using it into Y, which becomes very fast".**

I believe it conveys the major information of my thesis, meaning that I have developed an acceleration protocol for this particular solver. This solver has now become VERY fast (more than exponentially), and I want to convey this information.

However, I am not happy with the 'superfast' part, I find it a bit comic-like but it's the only word that I could think of that fits in this title formulation.

I tried to find synonyms or single-word expressions for

- 'accelerated' (can't use this, repetition)
- 'very fast' (not keen on using adverbs by describing a solver)
- 'augmented' (not contains the acceleration part)

All in all, I think there is a better word than 'superfast'.

**EDIT:**

This is the [synonym research](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/acceleration?s=t)  I've conducted:

- 'accelerated' -> 'sped up', 'hastened up' (ugly)
- 'very fast' -> 'agile', 'nimble', 'quick', 'swift', 'rapid' (still not convinced, because it applies to a solver, a program, that has been tuned to be amazingly fast)
- 'augmented' -> 'boost', 'enhance', 'improve', 'upgrade' (improved, too generic)

Comment: Why did none of the thesaurus suggestions fit?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: @HotLicks I will improve my question, but the bottom line is that none of the words I've searched for seem to be appropriate, with the only option being 'superfast', which is NOT my intention to use

Comment: Please edit your question and explain to us why *advance, expedite, further, hasten, quicken, spur, stimulate, hurry,* and *impel* do not suit your needs.

Comment: Please look in a thesaurus for the word "accelerate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **rapid** and **high-speed** spring to mind, conveying the intended meaning.

You can also rephrase the first part, allowing you to use "accelerated" later.

(i.e "On the rapid development of kinetic Monte Carlo Methods: accelerated Master Equation Solver for gas phase chemistry")

Comment: This shift is very interesting, I will try it out (rn I am compiling a set of titles)